# How to get a specific HTML element of a page (bs4)

Tags: python, html

```
import requests, bs4, webbrowser

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords='
keywords = "keyboard"
full_link = url + keywords
res = requests.get(full_link)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
webbrowser.open(full_link)

a = soup.find('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'})
print(a)
```

Hi, I'm trying to get a very specific html element that is buried deep in divs but to no avail. Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal" title="AmazonBasics Wired Keyboard" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005EOWBHC" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><h2 data-attribute="AmazonBasics Wired Keyboard" data-max-rows="0" class="a-size-medium s-inline  s-access-title  a-text-normal">AmazonBasics Wired Keyboard</h2></a>
```

and this is buried pretty deep. I want to get the href of this element, but currently my variable a returns None.

Comment: Make sure Amazon is not blocking your request. Try `print(res.status_code)` right under `res = requests.get(full_link)`. I am getting a `503` when I run your code most likely because I am sending a request without headers that looks like bot traffic.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting blocked as well. So besides that, there are no actual errors in my code?

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I pass the HTML you provided in as a string to BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`findAll`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) and supply the classes as an array. For example:

```
a = soup.findAll('a',  {'class': ['a-link-normal', 's-access-detail-page', 's-color-twister-title-link', 'a-text-normal']})
```

But I would also recommend against such specific class selection. The only one you really need is *probably* `s-access-detail-page`

Comment: It's not needed to supply classes in a list, at least in bs4 4.6.0 and Python3.6.